# c++: new return a type but compiles ok

Tags: c++

I am testing a C++ program (demonstrating a decorator design pattern) but found a strange problem. A sample code is like below. The error line had an extra `new` expression by mistake but surprisingly the code compiles and runs with error output (the decorator was output twice).

```
$ ./a.out
simple window with scroll bar with scroll bar
```

What did it happen here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Window {
public:
    virtual string desc() = 0;
    virtual ~Window() {}
};

class SimpleWindow : public Window {
public:
    string desc() { return "simple window"; }
};

class WindowDecorator : public Window {
protected:
    Window *window;

public:
    WindowDecorator(Window *window) : window(window) {}
};

class ScrollBar : public WindowDecorator {
public:
    ScrollBar(Window *window) : WindowDecorator(window) {}
    string desc() { return window->desc() + " with scroll bar"; }
};

int main()
{
    ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar(new SimpleWindow()); // error line
    cout << scrollBar.desc() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about which part of that surprises you?

Comment: Can I recommend you step back from pointers a bit and look up/exercise RAII a bit more? Those memory leaks hurt me.

Comment: It should either be: ScrollBar scrollBar = ScrollBar(new SimpleWindow()); or ScrollBar *scrollBar = new ScrollBar(new SimpleWindow()); The question is why the "new" operator on error line returns a pointer but it compiles (with error output though).

Comment: because `ScrollBar` is a type of `Window` and you have a contsructor that takes a `Window*`

Comment: Try marking your constructors `explicit` - a good habit to get into - and see what happens.

Comment: You are going to find that a great many things compile that do not make any sense and do not work. To compile you must merely be syntactically correct. Sometimes the compiler may throw you a bone and emit a warning, but... often no such luck.

Comment: @user2847598: "but it compiles (with error output though)" - what does that mean? What does "compiles with error output" mean?

Comment: Off topic philosophical question: Why does a `WindowDecorator` contain reference to a `Window`? Based on the name, I'd expect a `Window` to contain a `WindowDecorator`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @user4581301 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is an example of why we use `explicit` keyword for constructors in C++. (See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit))

You see, constructors with a single parameter, such as the one in your `ScrollBar` class...

```
ScrollBar(Window *window) : WindowDecorator(window) {}
```

...unless marked as `explicit`, will be used by compiler to perform implicit conversions, in your case, from `Window *` to `ScrollBar`. Such a constructor is also known as converting constructor.

So, what happens in this line...

```
ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar(new SimpleWindow());
```

...is compiler happily (implicitly) invoking your `ScrollBar(Window *window)` constructor one more time to convert `ScrollBar *`, you get from `new ScrollBar()`, to `ScrollBar`. This works, because:

1. `ScrollBar` is a subclass of `Window` (through `WindowDecorator`), and so `ScrollBar *` can be implicitly converted to `Window *`.
2. Constructor `ScrollBar(Window* window)` has a single parameter and is **not** marked `explicit`, so you get an instance of `ScrollBar` from the pointer returned by `new ScrollBar()`.

---

This is most likely not what you had in mind when writing your constructor, so you should probably rewrite it as:

```
explicit ScrollBar(Window *window) : WindowDecorator(window) {}
```

This should cause the surprising line to cause a compilation error.
It's generally a good idea in C++ to always use `explicit` for single-argument constructors by default, removing it only when you intentionally decide to allow implicit conversion semantics.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard (4.10 Pointer conversions)

> 3 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base
>   class (Clause 10) of D....

And (4 Standard conversions)

> 1 Standard conversions are **implicit conversions** with built-in
>   meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A
>   standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in
>   the following order:

....

> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions,
>   floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point
>   conversions, floating-integral conversions, **pointer conversions**,
>   pointer to member conversions, and boolean conversions.

In this statement

```
ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar(new SimpleWindow());
```

in the right side there is a pointer of the derived class `ScrollBar` that can be converted to a pointer of the base class `Window`.

The class `ScrollBar` has conversion constructor

```
ScrollBar(Window *window) : WindowDecorator(window) {}
```

that is called in the statement above.

Comment: Thanks for the info and explanation. I wish I could accept both answers.